# continuous bounded function on the bounded open interval ]a,b[ that is not uniformly continuous on ]a,b[

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Does someone know a continuous bounded function on the bounded open interval $]a,b[$ that is not uniformly  continuous on $]a,b[$.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

$\sin\frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,1)$ is a standard example, I believe.

Comment: The same kind of modification of a nonconstant, continuous, periodic function on $\mathbb R$ should do the trick.

Comment: In fact, it would do to use any nonconstant, continuous, bounded function, wouldn't it?

Comment: I don't think so, for instance take one period of sine and then smooth it out to a constant function elsewhere. Explicitly:$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\sin x\quad\text{if } x\in[0,2\pi]\\0\quad\text{if }x\not\in[0,2\pi]\end{cases}$$

Comment: Of course, you can weaken the condition that the function should be periodic. The key property is that it has variation around arbitrarily large real numbers in its domain.

Comment: Touche, although periodicity is still a ways away. Edit: well, you took the words out of my mouth.